# Stratum mining.notify help

Tags: mining, hash, protocol, stratum

So, I was working on my own mining client which it works on some ubiq pools, now im trying to make it work with Ethereum on ethermine.org pool which uses stratum, how do I handle the data recieved on the mining.notify message from the stratum protocol?

This is what I am currently getting:

```
{
"id":6,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"mining.notify","params":["1bb26087406b1884f19115d6ca0c5847f4ac4163159977225a92d873daae14d1",
"1bb26087406b1884f19115d6ca0c5847f4ac4163159977225a92d873daae14d1",
"cfa3e37c459ebd9b4138bd2141a52d89f6f8f671ecf91456f5a29176eb132fc0",
"0000000112e0be826d694b2e62d01511f12a6061fbaec8bc02357593e70e52ba",
false]}
```

On the pool that I started to work with the result from GetWork calls were three parameters, HeaderHash, SeedHash and Boundary which allowed me to build my Block header object like:

```
    public BlockHeader(string header, string seed, string boundary)
    {
        this.HeaderString = header;
        this.BoundaryString = boundary;
        this.SeedString = seed;
        this.HeaderHash = BlockHeader.StringToByteArray(header.Replace("0x", string.Empty));
        this.SeedBytes = BlockHeader.StringToByteArray(seed.Replace("0x", string.Empty));
        this.BoundaryBytes = BlockHeader.StringToByteArray(boundary.Replace("0x", string.Empty));
    }
```

How do I get headerhash, seedhash and boundary from the stratum resposne which has 5 elements?